# Needed help with deleting rails cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have been given a project of editing a website which is coded in RoR.

However, the changes which i make in the view file is not visible immediately after a hard refresh but after 15-20 mins, the changes reflect. I am guessing this has something to do with the RoR caching system.

Can someone please help me out ? The changes i made are purely HTML based like changing HTML attributes,  filenames etc...

Comment: Even if i change the name of the views folder to something like views_x the whole application still runs perfectly !

Comment: Does this happen in development mode or only in production?

Comment: How do i find out what the currently running mode is ?

Comment: If you are running locally, it is most likely in development mode.

Comment: Its running on an online server, but its an ip address.

Answer (score 4):

When the app is running in production environment, it caches everything in memory. You need to restart the application to reread all those files.

If you're running passenger you can restart the app by updating/touching/creating the `tmp/restart.txt` file. It's enough if you just update the modification timestamp:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Comment: Yes, im running mod_passenger.
However, there is no restart.txt file

Comment: The file will be created by *touch*, Passenger will then notice the file, remove it and restart your app.